# Does Spark's reduceByKey use a constant amount of memory, or a linear one in the number of keys?

Tags: apache-spark, mapreduce, apache-flink

As far as I know there are solutions of external sorting and/or in Hadoop MapReduce that allow for a constant amount of memory, not more, to be used when sorting/grouping data by keys for further piping through aggregation functions for each key.

Assuming that the reduce state is a constant amount as well, like addition.

Is this constant-memory grouping/sorting available for Apache Spark or Flink as well, and if so, is there any specific configuration or programatic way of asking for this constant memory way of processing in the case of reduceByKey or aggregateByKey?

Answer (score 0):

Both systems needs to implicitly perform the operation as the Java processes get only a fixed amount of main memory. Note that when the data to sort gets much larger, data needs to be spilled on disk. In the case of sorting and depending on your query, it may mean that the complete dataset needs to be materialized on main memory and disk.

If you are asking if you could limit the memory consumption of a specific operator, then things look much more complicated. You could limit your application to one specific operation and use the global memory setting to limit the consumption but that would result in complicated setup.

Do you have a specific use case in mind, where you would need to limit the memory of a specific operation?

Btw you can consider Spark and Flink to supersede Hadoop MapReduce. There are just a couple of edge cases, where MapReduce may be able to beat the next generation systems.